# Why Mathematica gives complex number in this case?

Tags: functions

Here is my code

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

delta[n_]:= Sqrt[2 Log[n]/(n^1)]

t[n_] := (n-1)/2 - (n - 1)*(delta[n]+1)/2

n=20;

f[n_] :=SetPrecision[ (n - 1)*(1 - Exp[-(n - 1)*(delta[n]+1)/2]*((E* ((n - 1)*(delta[n]+1)/2))/(t[n]))^t[n] )-(n-2),1]

N[delta[n]]

N[t[n]]

N[f[n]]
```

I didn't see the function $f$ should output complex number, since I don't have square root of negative value in the formula.

But the Mathematca gives complex number, why is that? Am I missing something? Thanks a lot for any help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

delta[n_] := Sqrt[2 Log[n]/(n^1)]

t[n_] := (n - 1)/2 - (n - 1)*(delta[n] + 1)/2

f[n_] := (n - 1)*(1 - 
     Exp[-(n - 1)*(delta[n] + 1)/2]*((E*((n - 1)*(delta[n] + 1)/2))/(t[n]))^
       t[n]) - (n - 2)
```

For the function to be real,

```
fd = FunctionDomain[f[n], n] // Simplify

(* ((-1 + n) Sqrt[Log[n]/n])/Sqrt[2] ∈ Integers && n > 1 *)
```

More specifically,

```
Assuming[n ∈ PositiveIntegers,
 FunctionDomain[{f[n], n ∈ PositiveIntegers}, n] // FullSimplify]

(* False *)
```

Graphically,

```
ReImPlot[f[n], {n, 2, 30}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, 
 MaxRecursion -> 15, 
 PlotHighlighting -> Placed["Dropline", 20],
 PlotLegends -> Placed["ReIm", {.85, .5}]]
```

[image]

To see the imaginary part more clearly,

```
LogPlot[Abs[Im[f[n]]], {n, 2, 30},
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 MaxRecursion -> 15,
 PlotHighlighting -> Placed["Dropline", 20]]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! but I would need to plot the function f instead of Abs[Im[f[n]]]. I tried plotting f[n] but there is no graph in the plot..

Comment: Complex values cannot plotted with `Plot`.  Use `ReImPlot`